# How to get rid of the right header

Tags: header-footer, format, remove

Maybe it is easy to do but I've been trying to remove the right header that shows in my document. I think it could be done by using the *titlesec* package but I have no idea.[image]

***Edit***
Here is the preamble code I'm working with (I don't really know how to split several lines in code text here, sorry :( )

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using. Your question is likely easy to answer but without more detail it is impossible, are you using `fancyhdr`?

Comment: If you think I should post some of the code I have please ask me to, I'm kinda new here :/

Comment: Do not worry, we were all new once upon a time `:)` LaTeX is pretty different to other coding stuff as one package or custom command could entirely change a possible solution, it requires (minimal) details to be able to help

Comment: @JamesT Thank you so much <3, I have edited the post with the preamble code.

Comment: The page you show has an even page number, so I think you mean a left-hand page, not a right-hand one.  You don't say what document class you're using, so I can't offer any more help, since that would require guessing.

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton So sorry, i forgot to add the first line: \documentclass[openany, a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}

Comment: It's probably easiest to wipe this out using a `\mark...`.  With `book`, you can enter `\markboth{}{}` immediately after the `\chapter` line.  This will also affect the headers on odd-numbered pages, but by default those should be filled in when `\section` is encountered.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you soo much! It works perfectly!